# How to use Install4j installer for upgrade on non-install4j installation?

Tags: install4j

How can I upgrade my application with install4j of previously installed application which was build with non-install4j.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for that in install4j, but before the "Install files" action, you can copy files that should be preserved from the old installation directory to a temporary directory. Then you delete the old installation directory with a "Delete files or directories" action.

After the "Install files" action you use the "Move files or directories" action to move the preserved files back to the new installation.

Comment: is this approach detects the non-install4j previous installation location ?

Comment: No, that is not supported by install4j